# What is ischaemia exactly?

Tags: physiology, homework, pathology, pathophysiology

I think it is decreased blood supply to organs and tissues.
I also think it is the stopped circulation.
However, both ones cannot be right, I think.

What is ischaemia exactly?

Comment: Is _insufficient_ blood supply a better word?

Comment: I am asking this because we have too venous congestion which is decreased blood supply to tissue. So Ischemia and Venous congestion should be orthogonal terms.

Comment: As I understand it, venous congestion is one of several possible causes for ischeamia. So a venous congestion would lead to ischeamia, but ischeamia does not imply venous congestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ischaemia is lack of sufficient **perfusion** to a tissue.  Reduced perfusion could therefore mean decreased blood supply to organs and tissues *and could also mean* a complete cessation of blood flow to an area - therefore both can be correct as they are on a continuum.  **Infarction** is tissue death due to hypoxia which can result from ischaemia that is not swiftly resolved.